# Get the name between previous and next

Tags: mysql

I have stop table and I am trying to find the name `ZOB/Hauptbahnhof Bussteig` in the case I know the stop name of the previous one `LindenArcaden` and the stop name of the next one `LindenArcaden, ZOB/Hauptbahnhof BussteigSandstraße`? The id is incremented by one. The name is not unique and this order `Sandstraße`can be found at various Position in the table.
 I am trying to find the Name with the stop_id `25` in the fiddle but I am getting many names in between.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36ec9/2

How can I fix it?

**Code stops table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stops
 (stop_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
 name varchar(30) NOT NULL, 
 lat double(10,6) , 
 longi double(10,6) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching for all entrys between the first `LindenArcaden` and the first `Sandstraße`. To find the entry you want you can use

```
SELECT STOP_ID, NAME
FROM STOPS
WHERE STOP_ID IN (SELECT STOP_ID+1
                           FROM STOPS
                           WHERE NAME = 'LindenArcaden')
AND STOP_ID IN (SELECT STOP_ID-1
                           FROM STOPS
                           WHERE NAME = 'Sandstraße')
ORDER BY STOP_ID
```